# Multiplcation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script for taking data entered into a Price field on my editor and splitting it across a Pounds and Pence field based on the `.` symbol.

Now I've been asked if I could multiply the Price field by 1.2 and display the result in the Pounds field. The pence field would no longer be needed.

I have no idea if multiplication can even work and especially using decimal points... Can anyone explain how I should rewrite the below?

```
$('#price1').keyup(function(event) {
    if ($('#price1').val().indexOf('.') != -1){
        $('#pence1').val($('#price1').val().substr($('#price1').val().indexOf('.') + 1, $('#price1').val().lengh));  
        $('#pound1').val($('#price1').val().substr(0, $('#price1').val().indexOf('.')));  
    }else{
        $('#pound1').val($('#price1').val());
    };
});
```

Comment: `.lengh` is, most probably `undefined`.

Comment: You're probably better off using actual numbers. Do [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) with those strings.

Comment: In order to format the code in Markdown put three backticks (`\`\`\``) on a separate line before the code and three backticks on a separate line after the code.

Comment: Reformatted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to remark:

- Your current solution has a spelling mistake for `length`.
- Don't locate the decimal point. Instead use native JavaScript capabilities to evaluate the input. You can use `parseFloat()`, `Number()` or the unary plus operator for that.
- Once you have the numeric value, you can multiply using the `*` operator. As multiplication will also convert its operands to number, you don't even need the previous advice, although it is still good practice to first do the conversion to number and then do the arithmetic.
- Use the `input` event instead of the `keyup` event: input is not always the result of key events (think copy/paste via context menu, drag/drop, other devices...)

Here is the proposed solution:

```
$('#price1').on("input", function(event) {
    var num = +$('#price1').val(); // convert to number using unary plus operator
    // multiply, format as string with 2 decimals, and convert back to number
    num = +(num * 1.2).toFixed(2)
    $('#pound1').val(num);  // output
});
```

Comment: that solution works an absolute treat and thank you for the other pointers, all advise is welcome so thank you again!

The only issue is say I do 9.99 I get back 11.988 so I'll need to get that rounded in the Pounds field. I've done some Googling and there seems to be num.toFixed(2) solution which might work?

Comment: Yes, if the result must have at the most 2 decimals, then `toFixed` can be useful. See update of the answer.